# Como obter páginas numeradas usando o pacote Officer / Officedown?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

```
library(officer)
library(officedown)
```

Estou usando o `officer` e o `officedown` para gerar um relatório em Word a partir do Rmarkdown.
Também uso o próprio template do officedown (File > New File > R Markdown > From Template > Advanced Word Document {officedown}) para trabalhar.

No entanto, não estou conseguindo que as páginas saiam numeradas no output.

Aparentemente não há uma função que faça esse trabalho (seja usando o `officer` ou o `officedown`) tampouco a possibilidade de solicitar isso no YAML.

Tentei usar um arquivo do Word como referência (vide YAML abaixo). Neste documento .docx de referência habilitei a numeração da página. No entanto, o relatório que quero gerar, ainda assim, não sai numerado.

```
---
title: "XXXX"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: "Estudo_template.docx"
---
```

Dei uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560994/rmarkdown-to-word-output-insert-page-number-for-word-document) mas não ficou claro para mim o que seria o tal "placeholder para o número de página" do qual o usuário fala. Pesquisando, só encontrei referência a placeholder de citação no Word (Referências > Inserir Citação > Adicionar Novo Espaço Reservado) que não serve para inserir número de página.

Answer (score 0):

O Word possui algumas ferramentas que podem automatizar algumas tarefas, como a numeração de páginas. Na versão 16.55 do Word para macOS, a paginação de documentos é feita da seguinte forma. Vá ao menu `Insert > Page Numbers...`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na caixa de diálogo aberta, selecione a posição da paginação na página e como ela será alinhada. No meu caso, escolhi a numeração embaixo da página e alinhada à direita, além de definir que a primeira página seria numerada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao compilar um documento com 7 páginas, é possível ver abaixo que a página 6 foi numerada corretamente, e que ainda há uma nova página na sequência.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os menus podem ser diferentes em outras versões do Word e em outros sistemas operacionais, mas a lógica básica desta operação deve ser a mesma. Basta encontrar o menu correto.

Comment: Oi Marcus obrigado.
Esse é o procedimento para placeholder?
Acredito que esse procedimento que você indicou, no Word para Windows, se faz: Inserir > Número de Página > Início da Página.
Fiz esse procedimento no .docx que estou usando como referência mas ainda assim isso não viabiliza um documento com páginas numeradas quando gero um novo documento no RMarkdown
Não sei se isso tem algo a ver com "estilo" (pois as alterações no RMarkdown) só se efetivam quando faço a mudança na guia "Estilos" (Página Inicial > Estilos).
A questão é que não vejo a opção de numeração no guia de "Estilos"

Comment: Vc consegue gerar um RMarkdown com paginação numerada baseado em um .docx de referência usando esse método que vc mencionou? Pergunto porque fica pensando se não seria uma questão de versão do office. Enfim, se vc conseguir, me avisa por favor

Comment: Sim, consegui. Usei um .docx seguindo os passos que apresentei, sem nenhuma formatação adicional, e funcionou para mim.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Marcus. Por aqui continuo sem conseguir. Não sei se é algum problema de versão do Word.

Comment: Marcus, uma dúvida: quando vc faz o knit, o documento gerado já surge com o número de página? Ou é necessário realizar manualmente "Inserir >  Número de Página > Início da Página"? Fazendo algumas modificações na numeração do documento usado como template (por exemplo: aumentando a fonte e deixando-a em vermelho) me dei conta que o template está de fato funcionando: o que estava faltando era justamente fazer o procedimento manual de inserir a numeração. Fazendo isso, me dei conta que o meu problema é, de fato, como fazer com que o documento seja gerado já com o número de página.